# hashCode() method for related entities

Tags: java, jpa, hashcode, entities

I read that when using JPA you should implement hashCode()/equals() for your entities.
So Eclipse for example has this nice feature to generate those methods for the classes.

But what fields do i have to choose?
I read that choosing the Long id; field of your entity is not a good idea. (right?, why?)
One should use a business key (some fields of the entity which can be used to identify the entity. right?) in the hashCode()/equals() methods.

Considering following scenario:
1:n relation between A and B...
is it a good idea to use those references in the hashcode() method?
if i do so i sometimes run into java.util.ConcurrentModificationException or Stackoverflow exceptions.
What about collections variables? i think i should not  use those in my hashcode() function... 
can somebody give me hints?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the fields (as few as possible) that will uniquely identify the object. If it were a Person it might be first, middle and last name. Or better still, Social Security Number if US Person. I don't see any issue with using a DB ID so long as the table cannot contain duplicate entities. In general, the identity of an object should not require checking the identities of it's associated objects (the 1:n relationship) but just the local fields.

Comment: Thank you for this answers :) As i understand it, one should not use the id primary key because at the time when the object is created (and NOT persisted into the database) this field would be null. So every new object would be equal to another new object. The problem is: what if my entity don't have any alternative fields which are considered to be unique? What fields should i use if not the id?

Comment: So abstractly, how would you consider two objects to be equal? i.e. if you were not using a DB and so didn't have an ID, how would you define equality of two beans? Do you just check every field? Seems like you might need to post the structure of the object in your question so that we get a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Equals and hashcode methods should be always implemented either on primary key or on your business key this is necessary if you want to adhere to requirements of your persistent manager. [Check here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own logic in hashcode to get the unique number.For example

you can do some combination of ^-ing
(XOR-ing) a class's instance variables (in other words, twiddling their bits), along
with perhaps multiplying them by a prime number.